# Scala "not found: type" error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am a scala noob and I am working on writing unit test cases for a scala spark program. When I try to run my scala unit test case using `sbt test` command, I get the following error

```
BasicACRStatsTest.scala:8: not found: type BasicACRStats

[error]   var basicStats: BasicACRStats = _
[error]                   ^
BasicACRStatsTest.scala:14: not found: type BasicACRStats
[error]     basicStats = new BasicACRStats
[error]                      ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
```

I am using intellij and when I am trying to refer the class `BasicACRStats` it shows `Cannot resolve symbol BasicACRStats` even though I have declared it in the correct package.

BasicACRStat.scala

```
 package com.company.analytics
 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.Statistics
 import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
 import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
 import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
 import collection.mutable


 object BasicACRStats {


   def main(args: Array[String]) {
   // Some code goes here
   }
 }
```

BasicACRStatsTest.scala

```
    import com.company.analytics
    import org.scalatest.FunSuite
    import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

    class BasicACRStatsTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter {
      @transient var sc: SparkContext = _
      var basicStats: BasicACRStats = _
      // some code goes here
    }
```

Simple.sbt

```
name := "basicACRStats"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "1.9.1" % "test"
```

Project Directory Structure

```
projectfoo
  .idea
  src
    main
      scala
        com
          company
            analytics
              BasicACRStats.scala
    test
      scala
        BasicACRStatTest.scala
  target
  simple.sbt
```

I am not sure on how to troubleshoot this issue, please share your thoughts and please let me know if you would require further information.

Comment: You need to `import com.company.analytics._` at the top of your test. Simply importing the package won't help.

Comment: I tried to add the above line at the top of my test case and still no luck. It shows the same error when I run the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BasicACRStats` seems to be an `object` in your sample code, not a `class`.

An object is a singleton and not a class/type. I *has* a type, in this case `BasicACRStats.type`, that there is only one instance of ever. Since it isn't a type calling `new BasicACRStats` is not valid Scala and neither is trying to use it as a type for a value.

What you want is probably to declare `BasicACRStats` a class. That would make the rest of your sample code make sense.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between an `object` and a `class` keywords in scala. However, when I changed it to `class BasicACRStats ` I get the following error message `[error] Could not run test BasicACRStatsTest: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized argument: -cp`

Comment: I would like to know if it is even possible to test the main class in Scala. How would one be able to test if the correct no of arguments are given to command line scala program for the `args` Array and check if the correct error message is printed to the console?

Comment: Calling the main method is easy, its just a method that takes an Array[String], check the side effects such as what is printed to the console, very hard if possible at all. What you normally would do is to extract your logic into clean testable functions/classes somewhere else, test those,  and then just use those in your main method.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I am now able to run my scala tests with Spark. I have also refactored the code such that I dont need to test the main class. Once I changed my main class `BasicACRStats` to object and ran `sbt test` on the command line, I was able to run the unit test for all the classes used in `main`.